# serve oracle service cloud Customer portal locally?

Tags: rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

I am working on customizing the **oracle service cloud customer portal**, but since OSvC provides only WebDAV to connect to it. It is very time-consuming to edit files and then upload them to WebDAV even for a single word change.
I am looking for a solution to serve it locally make desired changes and then upload the desired code to webDEV.

But after searching the file structure I can not make which framework it uses, I tried to use websites like https://builtwith.com/ and WhatRuns but they are also not able to find anything useful.

Although after searching in the file structure, I find some files of CodeIgnitor but the structure is way more different than the CodeIgnitor folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you will not be able to run Customer Portal locally.  While it is a fork of CodeIgniter from many years ago, there are server-side dependencies that will prevent you from running it in a local sandbox.

That said, it is possible to automate many of the manual tasks of interacting with WebDAV for change testing.  If you edit locally, then you can use scripting hooks or event RPA robots to automate some of the manual file movement.  Personally I have a flow to edit remotely in my test environment with an editor (like VSCode or Nova) that can connect to a remote server via WebDAV and edit files directly in the development area of a site. Then, when finished, I have a script that pulls down the latest version of all files and then allows me to commit changes to Git for SCM.

Another option is RPA.  You can develop a robot that can be run to automate the manual tasks that you face in your workflow.  Personally, I think that scripting is a better solution than RPA since you can automate all of the actions via scripting or a shell.  But, it's another option to consider.

Comment: ok so I see two approaches here, first, connect the code editor with WebDAV to make changes directly in the development area and for taking backup and all download all files from WebDAV to a local folder and then push it to git. 
The second approach is to create a hook in git for post-commit to make changes in the repository which will automatically upload code to webDAV.

Comment: The problem with the first approach is that downloading files from WebDAV every time is still time-consuming and git will serve no purpose here except for a time-consuming backup. 
The problem with the second approach is that for even a single change we need to make a commit which will result in too many commits, like 3 developers working together and each makes 20 changes a day then it will result in 60 commits each day.
Is there a way to find a mid-way?

Comment: which script you are talking about that pulls down the latest version of all files and then allows you to commit changes to Git for SCM. Can you provide that script?

Comment: The script is not public; it's one that I have written for my own use and workflow.  It's implemented as a Git hook, actually, and will download/upload the required files that have changed since the last commit.  You can implement a flow that works for you...it could even be a simple as using a WebDAV compatible program like Cyberduck to sync your folder structure as opposed to writing a custom script.  There are lots of tools that do that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of "Live editing" the OSvC CP code is to connect to WebDav via a software that supports it like `Mountain Duck` which uploads your code to OSvC on save.

OR use the better solution Windows Explorer which supports connecting to WebDav and treating it like a network drive, by going on `My Computer -> Computer -> Map Network  Drive` then put `https://yoursite.custhelp.com/dav/cp` click Next then you'll be promoted to login using your OSvC login.